# Add a specific character between specific numbers in a string column in pandas datafrane?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a column of strings and I need to insert a character at a specific index. For example, this is my column in a pandas DataFrame:

```
16923ABCD
16928ABCD
16917ABCD
16934ABCD
16912ABCD
```

The expected output is as follows (I have inserted character 'A' at index 2, after '16'):

```
16A923ABCD
16A928ABCD
16A917ABCD
16A934ABCD
16A912ABCD
```

Comment: Do you have them in a list or a pandas dataframe?

Comment: I have in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Ok. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have these strings in list use a `for` loop and for each use the followings:

`A = A[:2] + 'A' + A[2:]`

If you have them in a column of a pandas dataframe, the following will help. Assume df is your dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['16923ABCD' ,'16928ABCD' ,'16917ABCD' ,
                               '16934ABCD' , '16912ABCD']})

df['column1'] = df['column1'].astype(str).str[:2] + 'A' +
                df['column1'].astype(str).str[2:]
```